# Optimize # purchases per month SQL script

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wandering whether there is a more optimized solution(s) for the query below:

```
select count(purchases.id)
from purchases right join purchase_items on purchases.item_id=purchase_items.id
where purchases.created_date >= '2017-06-01'
and purchases.created_date < '2017-07-01'
and purchases.cancellation_date is null
and purchases.pending = 0;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. `Right Join` is normally not used. Even MySQL internally converts Right join to Left join for further processing. It is harder to read as well
2. You have `Where` conditions on the left table in a Right join. It is basically equivalent to `Inner join`. You could change it to `Inner join` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an inner join and add indexes:

```
select count(*)
from purchases p join
     purchase_items pi
     on p.item_id = pi.id
where p.created_date >= '2017-06-01' and
      p.created_date < '2017-07-01' and
      p.cancellation_date is null and
      p.pending = 0;
```

An index on `purchases(pending, cancellation_date, created_date, item_id)` and `purchase_items(id)` would help for this query.